# Powershell iwr fails when attempting -SkipCertificateCheck

Tags: powershell

Using **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)** (version 5.1.18362.145) and attempting to use `Invoke-WebRequest` it fails when using the `-SkipCertificateCheck`.

I don't know what to do about this as it seems to be documented on the [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7). I have tried running `Update-Module` just in case the module was an old version however that has not rectified the issue.

Command:

```
iwr -SkipCertificateCheck google.com -UseBasicParsing -Method Head
```

> Error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'SkipCertificateCheck'

At line:1 char:5
+ iwr -SkipCertificateCheck google.com -Method Head
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand`
```

Does anyone know how to get **`Invoke-WebRequest`** to work without checking certificates?

The overall goal of this is to use **`Invoke-WebRequest`** with a site that has a self signed certificate.

Comment: have you read the docs for that cmdlet? [*grin*] that parameter was added with ps6. **_it does not exist with ps5.1_**.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`SkipCertificateCheck` is not available on [5.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-5.1), you're most likely looking at the wrong version of PowerShell. This is a common workaround used for Untrusted Certificates.

```
add-type @"
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
    public bool CheckValidationResult(
        ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
        WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
            return true;
        }
 }
"@
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
Invoke-WebRequest https://expired.badssl.com/
```